# glDeleteTextures, leaking?

Tags: qt, opengl, memory-leaks, behavior

I found a rather disguting behaviour of glDeleteTexture, deleteing only parts of the aqcuired memory (GPU side and as Textures get saved back for the sake of speed in RAM), which in my case, is a showstopper bug, my program eating up all memory.

**I don't want/require you to read all of the code, it's just a demo, I'd rather know how to actually use glDeleteTextures so it does *not* leak *any* memory.**

The example code requires Qt 4.5 or later to compile:

**glleak.pro**

```
QT += opengl

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    glleak.cpp
HEADERS += glleak.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QtGui>
#include "glleak.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    glleak gll(0);
    gll.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**glleak.h**

```
#ifndef GLLEAK_H
#define GLLEAK_H

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>

class glleak : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    glleak(QWidget* parent = 0);
    virtual ~glleak();
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void drawScene(GLenum mode);

    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event);

    void hardcoreTexturing();
private:
    QList<GLuint> texels;

};

#endif // GLLEAK_H
```

**glleak.cpp**

```
glleak::glleak(QWidget* parent) :
        QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

glleak::~glleak()
{
}


void glleak::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glLineWidth (1.5f);
    glPointSize(4.5f);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

void glleak::resizeGL(int w, int h){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-w/2.0, w/2.0, h/2.0, -h/2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void glleak::paintGL(){
    glPushMatrix();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    drawScene(GL_RENDER);
    glPopMatrix();
}




void glleak::drawScene(GLenum mode){
    qDebug() << "drawed #" << texels.count() << " Textures";
    hardcoreTexturing();
}


void glleak::hardcoreTexturing(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    for ( int i(0); i<texels.count(); ++i){
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1.1f*i, 2.2f*i, 0.0f);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texels.at(i));
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2i(0,0);
            glVertex2i(-128,-128);

            glTexCoord2i(0,1);
            glVertex2i(-128,128);

            glTexCoord2i(1,1);
            glVertex2i(128,128);

            glTexCoord2i(1,0);
            glVertex2i(128,-128);

        }
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}


void glleak::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int n(50);
    if (event->delta()>0){
        qDebug() << "gen textures";
        for (int i(0); i<n; ++i){
            QImage t("./ballmer_peak.png","png");
            GLuint tex(0);
            glGenTextures(1, &tex);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
            glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits() );
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
            texels.append(tex);
        }
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "del textures";
        for (QList<GLuint>::iterator i(texels.begin()); i!=texels.end();){
            glDeleteTextures(1, &(*i));
            i = texels.erase(i);
            if (--n <= 0)
                break;


        }
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        updateGL();
}
```

**ballmer_peak.png**
A Image to load and render

Note: Compile demo: Just put it all in a folder, rename your image to **ballmer_peak.png**, call qmake, make, ./glleak
Note: ***Demo usage:* Use mousewheel to generate or delete 50 Textures at once**

If I use glDeleteTextures completly wrong, please tell me how to use it.
I am way out of ideas as my usage complies to the official OpenGL [glDeleteTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml) usage.

Comment: I now know the whole leak occures within the heap. Thanks to gnome-system-monitor.

Comment: If you are running it on linux, you could try running it through valgrind to see what it says the source of the leak is.

Comment: Actually I exclusivly speak about linux. Valgrind is quite useless, as it tells me all about possible leaks within Qt libs. So I get wicked sick amount of spam from valgrind, though I must admit I am not to familiar with valgrind. If you can give me any good advice, I'd be thankfull.

Generally it looks like a nvidia binary driver shortcomming I have to handle (I did not check my Intel powered laptop)... maybe I do that tomorrow if I got some sparetime.

Comment: Intel GPU/CPU behaves the same.

Comment: Just a random thought, did you try to remove the QImage creation from your loop ? Or to remove it completely ? This way you could actually rule out any possible memory leak in Qt image loading code.

Comment: I just checked that, using a single static QImage, which initalizes the QImage only once.
Same result as before. But thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the reason for your leak, but for starters you are using glGenTextures wrongly.

1) You should not put this inside the for loop which initializes the textures.  You need to put it before the loop and call it ONCE, with the number of textures required as the first parameter.  Say n == 50:

glGenTextures(50, &tex);

2) tex should be a static array of n GLuints and should be persisted (not an auto variable as you have it!) until glDeleteTextures has been called, again, ONCE - not in a loop:

glDeleteTextures(50, &tex);

Think of tex as a repository for storing texture ids.  It is important you use it and not say a separate QList, as you have done, for binding textures, since (as specified in the OpenGL reference) there is no guarantee that the texture ids will be a contiguous set of integers.  I should imagine your leak happens because internally OpenGL loses the original pointer to the local (auto) variable you used to generate each texture, so the texture memory becomes orphaned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1) + 2) where is this information from?
"there is no guarantee that the texture ids will be a contiguous set of integers" this does not matter in the above implementation.
"I should imagine your leak happens because internally OpenGL loses the original pointer to the local (auto) variable you used to generate each texture, so the texture memory becomes orphaned" Totally speculative. This would mean a textures being uncopyable (again not in the docs).
and the "pointer" actually only is a pointer to an array of guints (identifieres!! no actual objects!!!)
Prove your things!

Answer (score 1):

I did not run your example code, but I get a similar thing on Windows7-64bits. Using per-texture glGenTextures() and glDeleteTextures(), it might leak memory, but I'm seeing my thread's handle count increase (in TaskManager for example, but I can also check it from the source).
It seems glDeleteTextures() does not release a handle. Perhaps it'd do it later on, but 24-hour tests indicate it never releases the handle. Seems like a leak inside the driver (nVidia GTX285, driver 270.61).
Eventually indeed the program runs out of memory. I'm beginning to think it's a driver issue...

Comment: Not sure what you mean; just watching the Task Manager does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that looks wrong in your code. So... What makes you think you have a memory leak ? What makes you think it's textures specifically that leak ?

It is possible, but highly unlikely, that the OpenGL implementation you use leaks. That would be implementation specific.

Whatever the mechanism you use to look at memory leaks, what happens once you free the OpenGL context ?

Comment: When I free the the texture, only about 1 to 10% of the aquired memory(at a per texture basis gets freed).

My mehtod of watching this was the linux cmd tool top.

I know this code looks completly ok, but it fills 4GiB of RAM (and if I repeatetly scroll up and down.

I think its the textures, because there can't be anything else. Just  replace the texture stuff with simple Vertex Data (and increase the Number by 1000x) and it will not happen (as far as I can say, but I will give this a shot).

Maybe a nvidia Driver bug? This would explain it.

I keep the context across the whole program.

Comment: Sorry, it is incompareable to Vertex rendering, mindflaw.

I just don't see where it comes from. I mean the memory consumption is real ( it massivly slows down when the 4GiB barrier is broken, as Disk caching occures)

I really need help there, the code itself shoulnd't leak anything at.

Comment: time to instrument you allocation routines, look at memory consumption from a debugger to look at the heap allocations, lint your program, request heap dumps... There are a number of ways to look at memory leaks or ever-growing lists.

Comment: The point is, the leak, or at least mem that stays occupied, is there, I actually replaced the OpenGL part with doNothing() and just used lists to test if it is still there (with QImages), but it is not.

And I allready rechecked the demo with gdb for any signs, but nothing.

Comment: I misinterpreted your previous message. Well, I'm stumped. Any GL error ? otherwise, I'd try and reduce to a minimum program to submit a bug report.

Comment: I use this function to print all existing errors, but there are no errors, at least no gl errors.


void printGLErrors(){
    GLenum e(glGetError());
    while(e!=GL_NO_ERROR){
        qDebug() << "glerror [" << e << "] " << (unsigned*) gluErrorString(e);
        e=glGetError();
    }
}

That's the point, I don't know what to do anymore, I doubt it's within my code, I *think* it's a gfx driver bug :S

Lucky me :S

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call [makeCurrent()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qglwidget.html#makeCurrent) at the top of wheelEvent.

For paintEvent, resizeEvent etc, Qt provides an implementation which handles this before calling paintGL/resizeGL/etc, but for other events like wheelEvent you have to do it yourself.

Comment: It is not about getting it to work, it is all around memory leaking.
And I don't get your point anways, this has nothing to do with the exacution order, the texture gets spawn _after_ gl init and after the first resize event.

Comment: If memory is leaking, I would consider the possibility that the calls to glDeleteTextures aren't working.

Comment: So this was my point, but I don't get yours. The whole thing is running within one thread, the context is auto-auired by Qt at spawntime of QGLWidget.

If it was a generic error, _no_ gl commands would work, but it all draws.

So the question is why glDeleteTextures does not free the memory, while all other gl commands work flawless (even within wheelEvent).

Comment: Tested, and it does not change anything (as I expected).

Answer (score 0):

I might be doing this wrong, but when I compiled and ran your code I didn't run into any problems? Going up to 650 textures (can't increase further: get a 'killed' message then) and back my ram usage goes up from 1% to 24% and back to 1%. Going up to about 200 and back down repeatedly also doesn't cause problems: ram usage is still 1% at the end. From what I understand this would've caused massive leaks on your system? Ubuntu 10.10 here (Qt 4.7.0).

Comment: I did not investigate into thisany further as it seemed to be bug in mygpudriver(which I can not fix). I will test this soon, though inbetween I switche my gnu/linux distro which may have an influence too.

Answer (score -1):

Your test on my system eats memory well, and not releases it immediatly when I delete all the textures, but if I wait for some time, memory is returned to system.
It seems that OGL driver uses some lazy memory releasing algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (QList<GLuint>::iterator i(texels.begin()); i!=texels.end();)
```

switch to

```
for (QList<GLuint>::iterator i(texels.end()); i!=texels.begin();)
```

Comment: I don't see the point, ’i = texels.erase(i);’ kills the iterator ’i’ and sets ’i’ to the next iterator ahead. All items get deleted properly. Please elaborate, I don't get your point.