# OpenGL glDeleteTextures leading to memory leak?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, malloc, glut

My program renders large jpegs as textures one at a time and allows the user to switch between them by re-using the "same" texture.

I call `glGenTextures(1, &texture);` once at the start.

Then each time I want to swap the image I use:

```
FreeTexture( texture );
ROI_img = fetch_image(temp, sortVector[tPiece]);

loadTexture_Ipl( ROI_img , &texture );
```

here are the two functions being called:

```
int loadTexture_Ipl(IplImage *image, GLuint *text)
{
    if (image==NULL) return -1;
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, *text );

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ROI_WIDTH, ROI_HEIGHT,0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
    return 0;
}

void FreeTexture(GLuint texture)
{
    glDeleteTextures( 1, &texture);
}
```

My problem is that after a couple of images they stop rendering (texture is all black). If I keep trying to switch I get this error message:

```
test(55248,0xacdf22c0) malloc: *** mmap(size=744001536) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Mar 19 11:57:51 Ants-MacBook-Pro.local test[55248] <Error>: CGSImageDataLock: Cannot allocate memory
```

I thought that `glDeleteTextures` would free the memory each time??

Any ideas on how to better implement this?

p.s. here is a screen of the memory leaks being encountered (https://p.twimg.com/AoWVy8FCMAEK8q7.png:large)

Comment: glTexImage* calls COPY the memory at the pointer you pass to it, usually storing it in special graphic memory. The original piece of memory isn't deleted when using glDeleteTextures. I don't know if this was your problem, since it wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I deallocate the original piece of memory?

Comment: @Zyx2000 Of course it frees the memory. What else would it do? Read [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml)

Comment: @VJovic It does never free memory not allocated by OpenGL itself, which is what I said. Neither does it say anything about memory being freed at your link. Also see [this page on the OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#Memory_Usage)

Comment: You should not delete nor reconfigure your texture (glTexParameteri(), glPixelStorei()), you should just call glTexImage2D() again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to reuse your texture, you shouldn't delete it with glDeleteTextures. If you do that, you need to create a new texture using glGenTextures, and I don't see you are doing it in the loadTexture_Ipl function.

Comment: I removed it from the function after reading this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658096/1267728

Comment: @AntWilson: But you didn't remove the `glDeleteTextures` that matches it. `glGenTextures` creates the texture name. `glDeleteTextures` removes it. They're pairs, like `new` and `delete`. If you `new` something, you can only `delete` it *once*.

Comment: That is the case when there is a lot of textures.

Answer (score 0):

`glGenTextures` and `glDeleteTextures` go in pairs. If you really want to delete your texture (maybe because you most likely won't be using that texture again), delete it like you already do and call `glGenerateTextures` again before setting a new texture